# jquery-ui-autocomplete filling other inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Im using the following code,

**JS**

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        function log( message ) {
            $( "<div>" ).text( message ).prependTo( "#log" );
            $( "#log" ).scrollTop( 0 );
        }

        $( "#input" ).autocomplete({
            source: "source.php",
            minLength: 2,
            select: function( event, ui ) {
                log( ui.item ?
                "SelectedName: " + ui.item.value + " -SelectedID: " + ui.item.ID:
                "Nothing selected, input was " + this.value );
            }
        });
```

**PHP/HTML**

```
<tr>
    <td colspan="2">Input</td>
    <td colspan="2" >
        <input class="glowing-border"  id="input">
    </td>
</tr>


<div class="ui-widget" style="margin-top:2em; font-family:Arial">
    Result:
    <div id="log" style="height: 200px; width: 300px; overflow: auto;"   class="ui-widget-content"></div>
</div>
```

This works perfectly. But im stuck here, because i wanna split the results into 2 parts.  Now, in the div gets displayed:

> "selectedName: theName - SelectedID: 12345"

But, i need to fill another input field with this two values, there ist an input field `<input id="selectedText">` and one `<input id="selectedID">`

How can i do this?

2.) When i type somthing in the "input", i get the matching text from the db only. Is there a possibility to display the ID as well in the Listbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
$( "#input" ).autocomplete({
        source: "source.php",
        minLength: 2,
        select: function( event, ui ) {
            log( ui.item ?
            "SelectedName: " + ui.item.value + " -SelectedID: " + ui.item.ID:
            "Nothing selected, input was " + this.value );
            if (ui.item){
                $("#selectedText").val(ui.item.value);
                $("#selectedID").val(ui.item.ID);
            }
        }
    });
```